# Disable TRACK/TRACE apache

Tags: apache, ssl, nginx

I have a question about TRACK/TRACE HTTP Methods.
I disabled TRACE from httpd.conf with TraceEnable Off.
When I try and test if it really is disabled this is what I get:

```
< HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
```

However, the full code is still returned. Is this normal?
When I test the TRACE method on google site I get an html containing 405 Method not Allowed.

I am running 2 sites on this server, Apache with Nginx reverse proxy. One with SSL and one without.

The non SSL returns 405 Method Not Allowed, both in Header Response and in HTML code.

The SSL one, returns 405 in Header Response but with full html code ( main page )

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Edit:
Response for non SSL

```
* Connected to example.com (xx.xx.xx.xx) port 80 (#0)
> TRACE / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: example.com
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 405 Not Allowed
* Server nginx admin is not blacklisted
< Server: nginx admin
< Date: Mon, 08 Jun 2015 11:26:45 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 166
< Connection: close
< 
<html>
<head><title>405 Not Allowed</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>405 Not Allowed</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
* Closing connection 0
```

Response of SSL site:

```
* Connected to www.example.com (xx.xx.xx.xx) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* Server certificate:
*    subject: OU=GT45927005; OU=See www.rapidssl.com/resources/cps (c)15; OU=Domain Control Validated - RapidSSL(R); CN=www.smartnation.ro
*    start date: 2015-05-03 09:14:54 GMT
*    expire date: 2016-05-05 19:37:10 GMT
*    issuer: C=US; O=GeoTrust Inc.; CN=RapidSSL SHA256 CA - G3
*    SSL certificate verify ok.
> TRACE / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: www.example.com
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
< Date: Mon, 08 Jun 2015 11:30:55 GMT
* Server Apache/2.2.26 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.26 OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_bwlimited/1.4 is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache/2.2.26 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.26 OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_bwlimited/1.4
< Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
< Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
< Pragma: no-cache
< X-Pingback: https://www.example.com/xmlrpc.php
< Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=6b7fbfb366741438c07a9041452ea469; path=/
< Set-Cookie: _pmxi_session=%7C%7C%7C%7C; path=/
< Connection: close
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< 
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!--[if lt IE 7 ]><html class="ie ie6" lang="en"> <![endif]-->

<!--[if IE 7 ]><html class="ie ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->

<!--[if IE 8 ]><html class="ie ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->

<!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--><html lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no" />

    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

    <meta http-equiv="content-language" content="en" />
etc...
```

Edit 2:
Config files (httpd.conf and nginx)

```
Listen 0.0.0.0:8081
Listen [::]:8081
Listen 0.0.0.0:443
Listen [::]:443
<VirtualHost xx.xx.xx.xx:8081>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /home/account/public_html
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    UseCanonicalName Off
    #CustomLog /usr/local/apache/domlogs/example.com combined
    #CustomLog /usr/local/apache/domlogs/example.com-bytes_log "%{%s}t %I .\n%{%s}t %O ."
    ## User account # Needed for Cpanel::ApacheConf
    UserDir enabled account
    <IfModule mod_suphp.c>
        suPHP_UserGroup account account
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule !mod_disable_suexec.c>
        <IfModule !mod_ruid2.c>
            SuexecUserGroup account account
        </IfModule>
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_ruid2.c>
        RMode config
        RUidGid account account
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule itk.c>
        # For more information on MPM ITK, please read:
        #   http://mpm-itk.sesse.net/
        AssignUserID account account
    </IfModule>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/account/public_html/cgi-bin/


    # To customize this VirtualHost use an include file at the following location
    # Include "/usr/local/apache/conf/userdata/std/2/account/example.com/*.conf"

</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost xx.xx.xx.xx:443>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /home/account/public_html
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    UseCanonicalName Off
    #CustomLog /usr/local/apache/domlogs/example.com combined
    #CustomLog /usr/local/apache/domlogs/example.com-bytes_log "%{%s}t %I .\n%{%s}t %O ."
    ## User natsmart # Needed for Cpanel::ApacheConf
    UserDir enabled account
    <IfModule mod_suphp.c>
        suPHP_UserGroup account account
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule !mod_disable_suexec.c>
        <IfModule !mod_ruid2.c>
            SuexecUserGroup account account
        </IfModule>
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_ruid2.c>
        RMode config
        RUidGid account account
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule itk.c>
        # For more information on MPM ITK, please read:
        #   http://mpm-itk.sesse.net/
        AssignUserID account account
    </IfModule>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/account/public_html/cgi-bin/
    SSLEngine on

    SSLCertificateFile /var/cpanel/ssl/installed/certs/www_example_com_dfe76_6dcdf_1462477030_fd971317dfc02602ec168052ed2c7119.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /var/cpanel/ssl/installed/keys/dfe76_6dcdf_d9471fcd7e80d319080f6db604599d49.key
    SSLCACertificateFile /var/cpanel/ssl/installed/cabundles/GeoTrust_Inc__6473a1b25f37e0f134912eb5d8d02a9c_1653082772.cabundle
    #CustomLog /usr/local/apache/domlogs/example.com-ssl_log combined
    SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown
    <Directory "/home/account/public_html/cgi-bin">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>

    # To customize this VirtualHost use an include file at the following location
    # Include "/usr/local/apache/conf/userdata/ssl/2/account/example.com/*.conf"

</VirtualHost>
```

Nginx:

```
server {
          error_log /var/log/nginx/vhost-error_log warn;
          listen xx.xx.xx.xx:80;
          listen [::]:80;
          server_name example.com www.example.com;
          access_log /usr/local/apache/domlogs/example.com-bytes_log bytes_log;
          access_log /usr/local/apache/domlogs/example.com combined;
          root /home/account/public_html;
          #location / {
          location ~*.*\.(3gp|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|ico|wmv|avi|asf|asx|mpg|mpeg|mp4|pls|mp3|mid|wav|swf|flv|html|htm|txt|js|css|exe|zip|tar|rar|gz|tgz|bz2|uha|7z|doc|docx|xls|xlsx|pdf|iso)$ {
          expires 1M;
          try_files $uri @backend;
          }
          location / {
      error_page 405 = @backend;
          add_header X-Cache "HIT from Backend";
          proxy_pass http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8081;
          include proxy.inc;
      include microcache.inc;
          }
          location @backend {
          internal;
          proxy_pass http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8081;
          include proxy.inc;
      include microcache.inc;
          }
          location ~ .*\.(php|jsp|cgi|pl|py)?$ {
          proxy_pass http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8081;
          include proxy.inc;
      include microcache.inc;
          }
          location ~ /\.ht {
          deny all;
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

By the RFC specifying the behaviour of TRACK/TRACE (http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html), the behaviour of a call that is unsuccessful is not defined. You're encountering exactly this - undefined behaviour.

If a call via TRACK/TRACE succeeds, the following are true:

1. HTTP status code of 200
2. Content-Type of `message/http`

Anything else is considered a failure. A 405 is also considered a failure (client-triggered failure, hence the status code 4xx), so, as far as the RFC goes, this is fully compliant with how the request type is defined. So, the real question is, beyond the RFC, what were you expecting that differed with what you had? The error response?

Comment: The Error response is indeed 405 for both sites. I use this command to test the TRACE method: curl --insecure -v -X TRACE https://www.example.com for the SSL site and curl -v -X TRACE http://example.com 
The content of the response is 405 method not allowed for non SSL and full html for SSL one

Comment: I added the responses for both SSL and non SSL TRACE in my question maybe that would help

Comment: @chupya: The question remains - why do you care about the content response of a method that clearly is not allowed? The RFC doesn't define it. However, on the SSL version, the request still goes through to PHP (which seems to be the underlying method of generating the site's output). Can you show me the relevant configs in that case?

Comment: My question was if this is a normal behaviour, if the configuration for both nginx and apache are correct and if the TRACE method is really disabled. I am confused about the different responses that TRACE method gives. As per your request I added the config files.

Comment: Okay, so the different behaviour is expected. You have a `proxy_pass` in the case of a 405 to a php backend. So, yes, it's fully normal.

Comment: Thank you for this info. What do I need to do the have the same behavior on SSL? Can I create a server block in the nginx conf file that listens on 443, add the SSL options ( certificate, key ) used in httpd.conf and the rest of the configuration settings from the other block?

Comment: @chyupa - if you'd like the 405 on SSL to also go to backend, add a ProxyPass directive as follows: `ProxyPass http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8081`. If you'd like nginx to **not** proxypass, remove the line `error_page 405 = @backend;`. Second option is preferable.